# Cognos 11; how can I filter columns on a crosstab report independently

Tags: filter, cognos-11

I have a report with 16 categories as columns; my database (Snowflake) records can apply to one or more of the columns.

Is there a Cognos pre-built way to filter out records from one column without entirely removing them from the report as I need them to be displayed in a different column? I am trying to avoid writing 16 separate queries if possible.

Example:
Record 1: $100, Has Category_1 field = Yes
Record 2: $50, has Category_2 field = Yes

Report will show
Column: Category_1 | Category_2
Row: Amount

Category_1 should be filtered for YES and Category_2 filtered for YES as well. When I filter Category_1 is removes record 2 from the report and nothing is left to filter in Category_2 field

Comment: Have you thought about using a crosstab?   I'm not quite sure what the problem you are encountering is.  If the value for record 1 for category_1 is yes and (you don't say it so I need to guess) the value for record 2 for category_1 is no and you filter category_1 by yes, you should expect record 2 to go away.  You need to make the problem definition clearer.  An illustration of what you want to appear would be helpful.

Comment: I am ingesting database records and then categorizing them; but because a record can apply to multiple categories; each category is a separate field on the record with Y/N indicator values. When I build the report I bring in each category field next to each other, but I only want to show $'s where records are = Y in that category. In a normal crosstab or list, filtering on my first column which is my first category field it filters out all records where CATEGORY_1 = N; but that means it removes records that are = Y in other category fields because the record is removed from the entire report

Comment: Instead of removing the row, do you want to see a zero when filtering?